# Xpath Not Selecting Correct Element Using Splinter/Selenium Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, splinter

Not sure if I'm making a stupid mistake here, I've searched all over but I can't figure this one out. I'd really appreciate the help.

I'm trying to make a scraper to scrape Google Map Pack data. I'm using Splinter to do so. I've managed to select the div of each map pack item but I want to then iterate through and select the title (and other elements) of each of the divs.

However, when I try to do that it always selects the title of the first element even though I am running the find_by_xpath on the individual element.

Here's my code:

```
from splinter import Browser
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = Browser('chrome', options=chrome_options)


browser.visit("https://google.com")

browser.fill('q', 'roofing laredo tx')
# Find and click the 'search' button
time.sleep(5)
button = browser.find_by_name('btnK')
# Interact with elements
button.click()
time.sleep(5)
maps_elements = browser.find_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'VkpGBb')]")

for map_element in maps_elements:
    # print(map_element.text)
    title = map_element.find_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'dbg0pd')]/span").text
    print(title)
```

So what I want is:
J J Flores Roofing & Construction
HBC Roofing
McAllen Valley Roofing Co

but instead I get

J J Flores Roofing & Construction
J J Flores Roofing & Construction
J J Flores Roofing & Construction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

You got repeated result because from loop it selecting root element `//` it should be relative or `./` to select the childs but it still not work and maybe splinter bug. but try to use CSS selector

```
for map_element in maps_elements: 
    # select relative but failed
    #title = map_element.find_by_xpath("./div[contains(@class,'dbg0pd')]/span")
    title = map_element.find_by_css("div[class*='dbg0pd'] > span").text
    print(title)
```

---

typo in variable, remove `s` from

```
title = maps_elements.....
#title = map_element.....
```

Comment: You're right! Silly me. I've fixed that but I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. Are you sure that's the case? Everything seems the same to me. Which part of the SERP are you referring to?

Comment: Thank you!! That works. Must be a splinter bug. CSS selector works great. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

change your code:

```
maps_elements = browser.find_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'VkpGBb')]")

for map_element in maps_elements:
    # print(map_element.text)
    title = maps_elements.find_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'dbg0pd')]/span").text
    print(title)
```

to

```
title_elements = browser.find_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'dbg0pd')]/span")

for title_element in title_elements:
    title = title_element.text
    print(title)
```

Comment: Hi Yu, thank you for your comment that would work for getting the Titles but I also want to get the review stars, review number, website and phone number. I thought by selecting the div that contains each of these and then searching inside them would make it possible to get each of these but it seems it's not possible to search within an element?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct because you can not declare a variable at the for loop and then create that variable inside it. You would need to create the variable before initializing the loop in order for it to work.

```
title_elements = browser.find_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'dbg0pd')]/span")

for title_element in title_elements:
    title = title_element.text
    print(title)
```